# Notice: Undefined offset: different rows

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I'm trying to display images' metadata stored in 2 arrays…
When images has no Name, I'd like to display "no-name" instead. Here's how I display those now:

```
$imgs = array('img 1','img 2','img 3','img 4','img 5','img 6');
$imgNames = array('name 1','name 2','name 3',);

foreach($imgs as $files => $img)
{
    echo 'Image: '.$img.' and Name: '.$imgNames[$files].'<br>';
};
```

I expect the output:

```
Image: img 1 and Name: name 1
Image: img 2 and Name: name 2
Image: img 3 and Name: name 3
Image: img 4 and Name: no-name
Image: img 5 and Name: no-name
Image: img 6 and Name: no-name
```

but actual output is:

```
Image: img 1 and Name: name 1
Image: img 2 and Name: name 2
Image: img 3 and Name: name 3
Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in XX.php …
Image:img 4 and Name: 
Notice: Undefined offset: 4 in XX.php …
Image:img 5 and Name: 
Notice: Undefined offset: 5 in XX.php …
Image:img 6 and Name:
```

How can I fix this to display the default "no-name" strings?

Comment: thanks for correction @YakovL

Comment: You are welcome. Looking at your other questions, I'd recommend to invest a bit more efforts in formulating those: this will help you getting (more, better) answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `isset()` for this purpose. `$imgNames` array contains three elements while `$imgs` contains six and you have looped through the `$imgs` which means that it will run six times leaving `$imgNames` undefined for some of its elements. If `isset()` function returns false for current `$files` like `$imgNames[$files]` then it will be assigned a string `'no-name'`

```
    <?php
$imgs = array('img 1','img 2','img 3','img 4','img 5','img 6');
$imgNames = array('name 1','name 2','name 3',);

foreach($imgs as $files => $img)
{
  if(!isset($imgNames[$files]))
  {
    $imgNames[$files] = 'no-name';
  }
echo 'Image: '.$img.' and Name: '.$imgNames[$files].'<br>';
}
?>
```

Here is the [demo](https://3v4l.org/YUhtX)

Answer (score 0):

`ImagNames` has 3 elements while the other array has 5 elements.

You can add a check not to print it, if key doesn't exist

```
foreach($imgs as $files => $img)
{

 if(array_key_exists($files,$imgNames){

   echo 'Image: '.$img.' and Name: '.$imgNames[$files].'<br>';
 }
};
```